# Which audio codec is preferable to use for mp4 video?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, aac

I use standart codec for encoding and i don't like the quality of audio even if there is larger audio bitrate.

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.avi -i watermark.png -filter_complex \"scale=-2:'min(360,ih)',overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)-20:(main_h-overlay_h)-20\" -codec:v libx264 -profile:v main -preset slow -maxrate 400k -bufsize 800k -codec:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 320k -crf 20 output.mp4 1> error.log 2>&1
```

Comment: You will find anything to know about encoding AAC with FFmpeg here : https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC

Comment: libfdk-aac generally produces better quality